# How to resize the desktop application against the monitor size

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java application automatically resize to fit screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709561/java-application-automatically-resize-to-fit-screen-resolution)

I have to create a desktop application using Java Swing. It's working fine on a large screen monitor (18.5 inch).

I want to reduce the size of windows, but now controls are overlapping, some controls hide others, how will I handle my code for dynamically using the larger screen (18.5 inch) and smaller screen(14 inch)?

I handled the layout for all screens but screens will display correctly...only the controls are overlapping each other.

Comment: First, you need to think in pixels, not inches.

Comment: _I handled the layout for all screen_ if that means you did sizing/locating manually then you now experience the pain for such wrongdoing ;-) Use LayoutManagers.

Comment: @JohnU don't you mean portals?

Comment: @lynks - No, the atomic unit of screen space is the pixel. Everything else is elastic/faked/scaled/made-up depending on the particular system the user is using and cannot be relied upon to be the same from your screen to anyone else's.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one of your questions, you can get the window bounds, not including a task bar, with the following call.

```
Rectangle w = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

To answer the question you didn't ask, you **must** use a [Swing layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your GUI to scale from one monitor size to another.